# Delphi compiler error in assembler code for AsmProfiler

Tags: delphi, assembly

Try to run AsmProfiler downloaded from GIT, but when compiling I get an error:

> [dcc32 Error] mcThreadUtils.pas(line 470): E2112 Invalid register combination

Here is the code:

```
function GetCurrentContext: temp;
// Those three registers are enough.
asm
//@Label:
  mov [result.Ebp], ebx
line 470---  mov [result.Esp], esp   (invalid register combination)
  //mov ax, @@Label
  //call get_eip
  mov [result.Eip], eax;
end;
```

I try to build and run.. but get error and can't compile.

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using? There were some changes in compiler around assembly code and this sounds like a bug in the compiler. Can you please edit your question and add declaration of temp type.

Comment: rad studio 11.3 patch  and delphi 11 update 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the compiler gets confused by the members on the result that are named identical to the registers (but apparently only on `result.Esp`) as I can reproduce the behavior in Delphi 11.

To fix this simply put an `&`:

```
function GetCurrentContext: temp;
// Those three registers are enough.
asm
//@Label:
  mov [result.Ebp], ebx
  mov [result.&Esp], esp
  //mov ax, @@Label
  //call get_eip
  mov [result.Eip], eax;
end;
```